# Usind Sidekiq for Devise registration confirmation email

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, sidekiq

In my `model/user.rb` I have the following overwrite:

```
  def send_on_create_confirmation_instructions
    Devise::Mailer.delay.confirmation_instructions(self)
  end
```

It gets called when someone registers but throws this error:

```
ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (given 1, expected 2..3)
```

while this is the last line of the stack trace:

```
lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/devise-4.0.1/app/mailers/devise/mailer.rb:5:in `confirmation_instructions'
```

Whis is this method:

```
def confirmation_instructions(record, token, opts={})
  @token = token
  devise_mail(record, :confirmation_instructions, opts)
end
```

Clearly I'm passing the record, but not the token. I can't figure out where to get it from, in order to pass it, though. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are you call `confimation_instruction` directly. 
Try next:
`User.find(1).send_confirmation_instructions`

https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/bacd9d244cdf223b1fe080fa01b8c5bfc0b7a181/lib/devise/models/confirmable.rb#L41

It's takes care about token.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that worked. I saw an example from someone calling it directly. I wonder how did you know to look there?

Comment: I had been finding a point which use `confiramtion_instruction` and used find by it file and met this example after checked using.

Comment: Thanks for the insight, really valuable.